# Запуск copy команды Windows в консоле из-под Python

Tags: python, windows, cmd

Добрый день, столкнулся с вот такой проблемой. 
Нужно выполнить команду из Python скрипта:

```
copy \\example.com\lvl0\lvl2\lvl3 Windows
```

Пишу такой код:

```
path = r'copy \\example.com\lvl0\lvl2\lvl3 Windows'
path = path.split()
p2 = Popen(path, stdout=PIPE)
```

В итоге в переменной path находится:

```
['copy', '\\\\example.com\\lvl0\\lvl2\\lvl3', 'Windows']
```

И команда Popen не отрабатывает как нужно, потому что принимает некорректный путь с продублированными слэшами. 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно передавать путь в этих случаях?

Пробовал так решить эту проблему:

```
path = []
path.append[r'copy']
path.append[r'\\example.com\lvl0\lvl2\lvl3']
path.append[r'Windows']
p2 = Popen(path, stdout=PIPE)
```

Comment: Вы ошибаетесь, со слешами у вас все в порядке. Ищите проблему в другом.

Comment: `'\\'` - это **один** символ, а не два.

Comment: в сторону: не используйте `stdout=PIPE`, если вы не читаете из `p2.stdout`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На самом деле, ваша проблема - в том, что не существует такой программы как `copy`. `copy` - это команда командного процессора, и чтобы ее выполнить, надо запустить сам командный процессор:

```
path = ['cmd', '/c', 'copy', r'\\example.com\lvl0\lvl2\lvl3', 'Windows']
```

Comment: Все заработало. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess

subprocess.check_call(r'copy \\example.com\lvl0\lvl2\lvl3 Windows',
                      shell=True, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

- `shell=True` необходимо, так как `copy` это ["internal command"](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-internal.html), которая запускается из под `cmd.exe`
- `stdout=DEVNULL` подавляет стандартный вывод команды
- `subprocess.check_call()` запускает команду, ждёт её возвращения и выбрасывает исключение, если команда вернула ненулевой код возврата (указывает на ошибку).